# How does reactjs remove the comment from the UI on error in the tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been following the React tutorial (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and so far I get the general principle of rendering components based on state.

However the thing I don't get is, how does ReactJS remove a comment after the ajax call errors?

complete code plnkr can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TLoP7cmd9CEUm49U7nCm

this is the submit method from the tutorial (I changed nothing AFAIK)

```
handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({
      data: newComments
    }); //ok I get this.. being optimistic and all
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        //somehow the comment gets removed from the UI .. HOW?
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
```

Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the following :

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    this.loadComponentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadComponentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval) <-- this line
},
```

Since the error branch does nothing, the component will be reloaded with the state of the server after pollInterval.

Since the server did not accept the new comment, it does not exist on the server, so loadComponentsFromServer removes it.

If you remove the `setInterval` line, the optimistic comment is not removed.

Comment: Yes .. of course .. the interval. I did miss something obvious. That does happen to me when learning a new framework. Thanks for your effort man!

Comment: Debugging someone else's code is also part of learning new framework ;-)